# In chainsaw, what logFormat should be set for the given Log message shown below? I am reading for local file

Tags: log4j, apache-chainsaw

My log message is in following format. Its log4j's log.

Apr 26, 2013 11:43:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Note that the log message is in new line starting from INFO:....

I was try like: TIMESTAMP LOGGER LEVEL: MESSAGE

but its not working properly.

So what value should be set to logFormat property in chainsaw? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've added support for log formats whose records span multiple lines - use (LF) in the logFormat where a newline exists in your record format.

I've also updated the developer snapshot of Chainsaw which supports the newline (LF) field - you can download it here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy/

When building your Chainsaw LogFilePatternReceiver configuration, use:

Log format:

- TIMESTAMP LOGGER THREAD(LF)LEVEL: MESSAGE

Timestamp format:

- MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a